# In Windows phone Binding data in listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, listbox, windows-phone

I am newbie in windows phone app development.I Make one app in that i use web client to request for data to database which is in MySQL .i got response from that request but issue is that i use list box with item template and data template to bind response data in list box.when i change my URL which pass to web client it can't bind data in list box.even simply text of text block is doesn't display.but when i remove data template and item template from list box it will show that static data but not display bind data.please anyone help me...

Thanks in advance.I hope someone help me very soon...My C# code is :

```
public partial class chat_match_settings : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public chat_match_settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(profile_loaded);           
    }
    void profile_loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();

        var URI = new Uri("<http://www.mylocalipaddress.com/eyematch/rest1-7/api/>?");

        wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);

        wc.UploadStringAsync(URI, "POST", "action=login&uName=hiren&uPass=hiren123");         
    }       
    private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       try
       {
           var jsondata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);

           DisplayList list = new DisplayList(jsondata.profile.DisplayData);

           //profilelistview.DataContext = this;

           profilelistview.ItemsSource = list;

       }
        catch (Exception exc)

        {}        
       }

    public class DisplayList : List<DisplayData>
    {
        public DisplayList(DisplayData data)

        {
                          Add(new DisplayData
            {
                Username = data.FullName.ToString(),

                countryname = data.countryname.ToString(),

                Sex = data.Sex.ToString(),

                City = data.City.ToString(),

                AboutMyself = data.AboutMyself.ToString(),

                Job = data.Job.ToString(),

                Location = data.Location.ToString(),

                MatchSex = data.MatchSex.ToString(),

                Iam = data.Iam.ToString(),

                StartWorkHour = data.StartWorkHour.ToString(),

                Age = data.Age,

                EndWorkHour = data.EndWorkHour.ToString(),

                Language = data.Language,

                MessageMe = data.MessageMe.ToString(),

                Ilove = data.Ilove.ToString(),

                LookingFor = data.LookingFor.ToString(),

                BodyDescription = data.BodyDescription });


        }
    }
    public class DisplayList1 : List<ProfileImage>
    {
        public DisplayList1(ProfileImage profileImage)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization

            Add(new ProfileImage
                    { Value = "<http://localipaddress.com/eyematch/upload/images/2/>?" + profileImage.Value });

        }
```

and xaml code is:

```
                                 <Image x:Name="matchimage"/><TextBlock x:Name="matchpercentage"/>

                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=UserFeedBackForDisplay}"></TextBlock>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= Sex}" Foreground="Gray"  FontSize="16" Margin="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="/" FontSize="16"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Sex}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="/" FontSize="16"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Job}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="/" FontSize="16"/>
                                    <!--<ListBox Name="language"    Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16">
                                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=contactdata.Title}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ListBox>-->
                                </StackPanel>


                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=City}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="/" FontSize="16"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=countryname}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>

                                <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">

                                </StackPanel>

                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="About MySelf"  FontSize="30" ></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=AboutMyself}" Foreground="Gray" Height="60" Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="16"></TextBlock>

                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="I Am"  FontSize="30" ></TextBlock>

                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <TextBlock Text="I 'm " Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BodyDescription.BodyStyle}" Foreground="Gray"  Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap"  FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="/" FontSize="16"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BodyDescription.Hair}" Foreground="Gray"  Width="Auto" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text=" Hair " Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="/" FontSize="16"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BodyDescription.Eyes}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text=" Eyes " Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Iam}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="I Love" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Ilove}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="I'm Looking For" FontSize="26"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LookingFor}"  Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Message Me" FontSize="30"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MessageMe}"  Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Match Sex"  FontSize="30" ></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MatchSex}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel >
                                <StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="Start Working Hour"  FontSize="30" ></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartWorkHour}" Foreground="Gray"  FontSize="16" ></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="End Working Hour"  FontSize="30" ></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EndWorkHour}" Foreground="Gray"  FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Username}" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Location}" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="16"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: Please show your C# and XAML code.

Comment: I upload my code in that code i change my local ip address with myipaddress.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in the above example I have used wcf service , and for the For the connectivity to DataBase we have used ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

Then in the IService.cs we need to declare a method

```
          [OperationContract]
          List<string[]> UserDetails();
```

Then in the Service.cs we need to define this Method

```
        public List<string[]> UserDetails()
        {
            List<string[]> lsdUserInfoDetails =
                                    new List<string[]>();
            string[] allUserList;

            try
            {
                userDataConnection userContext = new
                                                   userDataConnection();

                var query = (from Info in userContext.UserInfo
                               select Info).ToList();

                foreach(var userdetails in query)
                   {
                       allUserList = new string[8];
                       allUserList[0] = userdetails.UserName.ToString();
                       allUserList[1] = userdetails.UserCity.ToString();
                       allUserList[2] = userdetails.UserState.ToString();
                       allUserList[3] = userdetails.UserGender.ToString();
                       allUserList[4] = userdetails.UserAge.ToString();
                       allUserList[5] = userdetails.UserDescription.ToString();

                       lsdUserInfoDetails.Add(allUserList);  
                   }


            }
            catch (Exception es)
            {

            }

            return lsdUserInfoDetails;
        }
```

And added the following code snipet in the MainPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
       List<User> userList = new List<User>();

        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


             UserServiceReference.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

              //Event handler after webservice completes operation.
             client.UserDetailsCompleted += new EventHandler<UserDetailsCompletedEventArgs>                                           

                             (serviceClient_UserDetailsCompleted);
             client.UserDetailsAsync();

        }   
    }

    //Completed event of the UserDetails
    public void serviceClient_UserDetailsCompleted(Object sender,UserDetailsCompletedEventArgs e )
        {
             try
            {

                var lsdUser = e.Result.ToList();

                foreach (var userData in lsdUser)
                {

                    User userObj = new User();
                    userObj.UserName =userData[0].ToString();
                    userObj. userCity = userData[1].ToString();
                    userObj. userState=userData[2].ToString();
                    userObj. userGender=userData[3].ToString();
                    userObj. userAge=userData[4].ToString();
                    userObj. userDescription=userData[5].ToString();

                    userList.Add(userObj);

                }

                //Binding Data to the userListBox
                userListBox.ItemsSource = userList;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.ToString();
            }

        }







    /// <summary>
    /// User class
    /// </summary>
    public class User
    {

        private string userName;
        private string userID;
        private string userState;
        private string userCity;
        private string userGender;
        private string userAge;


        public string UserID
        {
            get
            {
                return userID;
            }
            set
            {
                userID = value;
            }
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return userName;
            }
            set
            {
                userName = value;
            }
        }

        public string UserState
        {
            get
            {
                return userState;
            }
            set
            {
                userState = value;
            }
        }

        public string UserCity
        {
            get
            {
                return userCity;
            }
            set
            {
                userCity = value;
            }
        }

        public string UserAge
        {
            get
            {
                return userAge;
            }
            set
            {
                userAge = value;
            }
        }

        public string UserGender
        {
            get
            {
                return userGender;
            }
            set
            {
                userGender = value;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain it interms of windows phone for webclient not wcf .

Comment: I have json response .i deserilized it by jsoncovert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result); and i got  different language in response (like:hindi,English) .means array of language .i want to desterilized it and bind it to listbox . Can you tell me how it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

If data is coming correctly in e.Result as the way you want to display it in the listbox.you may look into the following.Here I am getting data from the wcf service.

lets say in your mainPage.xaml.cs  we can add the following code

as here I am using wcf service we need to write following

```
    // Constructor
             public MainPage()
             {
                 InitializeComponent();


                  UserServiceReference.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient();

                   //Event handler after webservice completes operation.
                  client.UserDetailsCompleted += new EventHandler<UserDetailsCompletedEventArgs>                                            

                                  (serviceClient_UserDetailsCompleted);
                  client.UserDetailsAsync();

             }    
         }


    //Completed event of the UserDetails
         public void serviceClient_UserDetailsCompleted(Object sender,UserDetailsCompletedEventArgs e )
             {
                  try
                 {

                     var lsdUser = e.Result.ToList();

                     foreach (var userData in lsdUser)
                     {

                         User userObj = new User();
                         userObj.UserName =userData[0].ToString(); 
                         userObj. userCity = userData[1].ToString();
                         userObj. userState=userData[2].ToString();
                         userObj. userGender=userData[3].ToString();
                         userObj. userAge=userData[4].ToString();
                         userObj. userDescription=userData[5].ToString();

                         userList.Add(userObj);

                     }

                     //Binding Data to the userListBox
                     userListBox.ItemsSource = userList;

                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     string message = ex.ToString();
                 }

             }
```

And in the Xaml we can bind data using itemTemplate and dataTemplate

```
    <ListBox Height="279"
                          Name="userListBox"
                          Background="White"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Margin="0,5,0,0"
                          >
                     <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                             <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"></StackPanel>
                         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                     </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                         x:Name="user"
                                         Width="600">
                                 <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserName"
                                            Text="{Binding UserName}"
                                            Foreground="Black"
                                            Width="100"
                                            Height="65"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                 </TextBlock>

                                 <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserCity"
                                            Text="{Binding UserCity}"
                                            Foreground="Black"
                                            Width="100"
                                            Height="65"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                 </TextBlock>

                                 <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserState"
                                            Text="{Binding UserState}"
                                            Foreground="Black"
                                            Width="100"
                                            Height="65"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                 </TextBlock>

                                 <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserGender"
                                            Text="{Binding UserGender}"
                                            Foreground="Black"
                                            Width="100"
                                            Height="65"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                 </TextBlock>

                                 <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserAge"
                                            Text="{Binding UserAge}"
                                            Foreground="Black"
                                            Width="100"
                                            Height="65"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                 </TextBlock>

                                 <TextBlock x:Name="txtUserDescription"
                                            Text="{Binding UserDescription}"
                                            Foreground="Black"
                                            Width="100"
                                            Height="65"
                                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                 </TextBlock>

                             </StackPanel>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                 </ListBox>
```

Hope it will help you in some extent,the only difference is here that I am getting data from the wcf service.

Comment: i try your code but i get json response from database and while i deserilize it and convert it in list it gives me error.i do following: var lsduser = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result).Tolist(); Is there any other way to do it.I hope you understand what i want to telling?

Comment: Why have you added two answers?